# tailwindcss ease-in-out is not working in react app

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

```
import React from 'react';

const LogoutConfirmation = ({ isOpen, onCancel, onConfirm }) => {
  if (!isOpen) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center z-50 bg-opacity-60 bg-red-900 ease-in-out duration-300">
  
      <div className="bg-black p-6 rounded-2xl shadow-md text-green-500 font-semibold">
        <p className="mb-4">Are you sure you want to log out?</p>
        <div className="flex justify-end">
          <button
            className="mr-2 px-4 py-2 bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 rounded hover:scale-105 duration-300"
            onClick={onCancel}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button
            className="px-4 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white rounded hover:scale-105 duration-300"
            onClick={onConfirm}
          >
            Log Out
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LogoutConfirmation;
```

i am trying to show this whole windows as a pop up that fades in when user clicks on logout but `ease-in-out duration-300` is not working for some reason i tried changing the duration to 1000 still it appeared suddenly instead of fading in

edit: if possible can anyone tell me a how can i block the background like when this pop up is there the background shouldn't be accessible like for now i can use the mouse wheel to scroll the page behind it...if there's a way to do it i would really like to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to tell the browser rendering engine you'd like the element to fade in. To do this, one could set the initial opacity of the element to `0` and then change it to `1`, thus allowing a CSS transition to run. Additionally, since we only conditionally render the element, we'd need to wait a frame for the element to be in the DOM before we trigger this change:

```js
const LogoutConfirmation = ({ isOpen, onCancel, onConfirm }) => {
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = React.useState('opacity-0');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        setOpacity('opacity-100');
      });
    } else {
      setOpacity('opacity-0');
    }
  }, [isOpen]);
  
  if (!isOpen) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={`fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center z-50 bg-opacity-60 bg-red-900 ease-in-out duration-300 ${opacity}`}>
  
      <div className="bg-black p-6 rounded-2xl shadow-md text-green-500 font-semibold">
        <p className="mb-4">Are you sure you want to log out?</p>
        <div className="flex justify-end">
          <button
            className="mr-2 px-4 py-2 bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 rounded hover:scale-105 duration-300"
            onClick={onCancel}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button
            className="px-4 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white rounded hover:scale-105 duration-300"
            onClick={onConfirm}
          >
            Log Out
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
        Open
      </button>
      <LogoutConfirmation
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onCancel={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        onConfirm={() => setIsOpen(false)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Otherwise, you could look at keeping the element in the DOM and using `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` to hide the element. However, this will also give a fadeout transition too:

```js
const LogoutConfirmation = ({ isOpen, onCancel, onConfirm }) => {
  return (
    <div className={`fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center z-50 bg-opacity-60 bg-red-900 ease-in-out duration-300 ${isOpen ? 'opacity-100' : 'invisible opacity-0'}`}>
  
      <div className="bg-black p-6 rounded-2xl shadow-md text-green-500 font-semibold">
        <p className="mb-4">Are you sure you want to log out?</p>
        <div className="flex justify-end">
          <button
            className="mr-2 px-4 py-2 bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 rounded hover:scale-105 duration-300"
            onClick={onCancel}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button
            className="px-4 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white rounded hover:scale-105 duration-300"
            onClick={onConfirm}
          >
            Log Out
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
        Open
      </button>
      <LogoutConfirmation
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onCancel={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        onConfirm={() => setIsOpen(false)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

---

Please note: I have intentionally not answered your other point regarding how you can block the background like when this pop up is there, since StackOverflow questions should keep to one question only. See [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/1406564).